# Android BroadcastReceiver Before Screen Off

Tags: android, event-handling, broadcastreceiver, wakeup, screen-off

Android Broadcast Receiver:

Is there any trick/event that can trigger just before screen is going to Off `android.intent.action.SCREEN_OFF`

OR

Any way to know if screen goes off by power press or by auto sleep function?

Answer (score 0):

Have you try to use de lifecycle methods? Every time the screen is Locked, the activity will call first the method onPause() and then onStop(), so you could override them to add your code